# BSON/Binary to string for MongoDB Object ID in Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on Change Streams introduced in MongoDB Version 3.6. Change Streams have a feature where I can specify to start streaming changes from a particular change in history. In native driver for Node.js, to resume change stream, it says ([documentation here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/ChangeStream.html))

> Specifies the logical starting point for the new change stream. This should be the _id field from a previously returned change stream document.

When I print it in console, this is what I am getting

```
{ _id: 
   { _data: 
      Binary {
        _bsontype: 'Binary',
        sub_type: 0,
        position: 49,
        buffer: <Buffer 82 5a 61 a5 4f 00 00 00 01 46 64 5f 69 64 00 64 5a 61 a5 4f 08 c2 95 31 d0 48 a8 2e 00 5a 10 04 7c c9 60 de de 18 48 94 87 3f 37 63 08 da bb 78 04> } },
        ...
}
```

My problem is I do not know how to store the `_id` of this format in a database or a file. Is it possible to convert this binary object to string so I can use it later to resume my change stream from that particular `_id`. Example code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Convert BSON Binary to buffer and back

```
const Binary = require('mongodb').Binary;
const fs     = require('fs');
```

Save _data from _id:

```
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/test');
wstream.write(lastChange._id._data.read(0));
wstream.close();
```

Then rebuild resumeToken:

```
fs.readFile('/tmp/test', void 0, function(err, data) {
  const resumeToken = { _data: new Binary(data) };
});
```